# Почему нету данных на сервере express

Tags: javascript, reactjs, express

Имеется код для отправки формы

```
    handleSubmit(event) {
    const login = this.state.login;
    const password = this. state.password;
    const repassword= this.state.repassword;
    if (password === repassword) {
        const userInfo = {
            login: login,
            password: password,
            repassword: repassword
        };
        const data = new FormData();
        data.append('json', JSON.stringify(userInfo));
        fetch('/regUser', {
            method: 'POST',
            credentials: 'include',
            body: data
        }).then(function(res) {
            console.log(res);
        });
    } else alert("Error");
    event.preventDefault();
}
```

И его обработчик на сервере

```
const express = require('express');
const app = express();
const bodyParser = require('body-parser');

app.use(bodyParser.json());
app.use(bodyParser.urlencoded({ extended: true }));

app.post('/regUser', (req, res) => {
    if(!req.body) return res.sendStatus(400);
    console.log(req.body);
});

app.listen(3000, ()=> {
    console.log("ARM-ZVIT Server listening on 3000 port");
});
```

Почему в консоль на сервере я получаю пустой обьект?

Answer (score 0):

```
handleSubmit(event) {
    const login = this.state.login;
    const password = this. state.password;
    const repassword= this.state.repassword;
    if (password === repassword) {
        const userInfo = {
            login: login,
            password: password,
            repassword: repassword
        };
        fetch('/regUser', {
            method: 'POST',
            credentials: 'include',
            headers: {
                'Content-Type': 'application/json'
            },
            body: JSON.stringify(userInfo)
        })
        .then(function(res) {
            console.log(res);
        });
    } else {
        alert("Error");
    }
    event.preventDefault();
}
```

Comment: Тоесть если запрос послан без указания заголовка, то bodyParcer не сработает? Спасибо

Comment: Вы посылали FormData, где в одном из полей содержался JSON. В этом ответе я убрал FormData и сделал всё тело в виде JSON